# Clarification on the definition of intersection graphs.

Tags: graph-theory, definition

I was reading Frank Harary's text and comparing it with Wikipedia's definition. Harary defined the family set $F$ whose set elements are vertices of the intersection graph to be **distinct** while Wikipedia defined $F$ to allow **non-distinct** set elements. What am I not understanding? Sorry if this is a silly question.
[image]

[image]
Source: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_number_(graph_theory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitions are not set in stone. Whoever wrote the Wikipedia article must think that the definition is better if we allow repeated subsets, while Harary does not. Just keep this fact in mind while reading any literature where the author talks about *intersection graphs* that there is a difference of opinion as to whether duplicate subsets should be allowed in the vertex set. Usually, though, the precises definition will not matter that much, or will be clear from the context.

Comment: Would it not affect the intersection number?

Comment: @TheLastCipher yeah I think it would. If you have a family of subsets $F$ of $S$ that contains duplicates such that it has Wikipedia-intersection-number $k$, then there is an easy way to represent the same intersection graph as a family of subsets without duplicates where you just add an element to $S$ for each pair of duplicate elements, making the Harary-intersection-number at most $k$ plus the number of duplicate pairs. The fundamental problem of calculating the intersection-number is equally difficult using either definition. The difference between the definitions is superficial.

Comment: I'm still confused. I think if the elements of F cannot be repeated then for instance a connected a connected graph of two cycles of length 3 will have an intersection representation of {{1,3},{1,4},{1,2},{2,5},{2,6}}. While if allowed to be nondistinct then {{1},{1},{1,2},{2},{2}}?

Comment: Ohhh okay. So the definitions doesn't help make it easier

Comment: @TheLastCipher yeah, the fundamental question is the same, and whether or not you allow duplicates in the definition is just a matter of the author's preference. Hopefully the literature prefers one definition over the other.